# Extracting a value from web URL

Tags: python

I am trying to extract value from a URL with the code:

```
import requests
import lxml.html as LH

url = "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=PFC&instrument=FUTSTK"

html = requests.get(url).content
tree = LH.fromstring(html)
node = tree.xpath("//*[@id='annualisedVolatility']")[0]
val = node.text
print(val)
```

...expecting the value from:

```
<span id="annualisedVolatility">38.98</span>
```

Would appreciate knowing where the error is.

Comment: And what happens?

Comment: @Daniel I get _None_

Comment: you can also use `beautifulsoup` or a `regexp` to retrieve desired value.

Comment: The DOM only contains `<td align="right"><b><span id="annualisedVolatility"></b></span></td>` - the rest comes from what looks like JSON and injected into the DOM later - you'll need to handle that yourself by pulling out the JSON... Look at the page source in your browser and go from there... Although looks like `<div id="responseDiv" style="display:none">` has text content that's the JSON - so soup that out and interpret it as a json object...

Comment: @ArtsiomPraneuski wanted to use just lxml or elementtree without bs. Code to handle is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why I got a downvote! Figured it out. Here is the code:

```py
import requests
import json

url = "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=PFC&instrument=FUTSTK"
html = requests.get(url).text
data=soup.find(id="responseDiv").text.strip()

d1 = json.loads(data)
d2=float(d1['data'][0]['annualisedVolatility'])
print(d2)
```